# Return result of primary table queried then append result of join to a property

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to tell .NET to create a new object, take properties from the first data set and append the result of a join to one of the properties of that newly created object

```
var projects = from p in projectSet //projectSet is DbSet<Project>....
               join lmp in LMProjects on p.ProjectID equals lmp.lmp_ProjectID
               where p.UserID == value
               select new Project { LMProject = lmp };
```

Here's the rub, I can tell it to create a new object, assign the result of the join (`lmp`) to one of it's property, but how to I tell it to use the result of `p` to initiate all the other values of the newly created object ? Is that even possible without manually assigning values (there are about 30 in `Project` class...)

I thought of doing this, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

```
var projects = from p in projectSet
               join lmp in LMProjects on p.ProjectID equals lmp.lmp_ProjectID
               where p.UserID == value
               select new { Project = p, LMProject = lmp };
```

The reason I'm doing this is I've got a database with no foreign keys and I'm trying to emulate navigation properties. (I can't change the model)

Comment: Is this the final query, i.e. do you need it to stay IQueryable for further processing?

Comment: For the moment, I've got no contraints.

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear. Currently your `var projects` is of type `IQueryable<Project`. Does changing it to `IEnumerable<Project>` work for you?

Comment: Also this seems to be LINQ to Entities (i.e. should be tagged `entity-framework`, not `linq-to-sql`)?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want to manually list all the fields in the `select` clause, you cannot do that directly because Entity Framework does not allow projection to entity types.

The only possible way is to combine your second approach to execute LINQ to Entities query agains the database with switching to LINQ to Objects context and doing the "fixup" and final projection like this:

```
var query = from p in projectSet
               join lmp in LMProjects on p.ProjectID equals lmp.lmp_ProjectID
               where p.UserID == value
               select new { Project = p, LMProject = lmp };
var projects = query.AsEnumerable().Select(r =>
{
    r.Project.LMProject = r.LMProject;
    return r.Project;
};
```

But note that this would change the context and the type of the `projects` to `IEnumerable<Project>`. Of course you can turn it back to `IQueryable<Project>` by using `AsQueryable` method, but it will be no more a real database query, so if you apply additional filters, ordering, paging etc., all they will happen in memory (only the `query` part will execute against the database).